# Implementing a sparse array in C# / fastest way to map integer to a specific bucket/range number

Tags: c#, algorithm

My initial problem is that I need to implement a very fast, sparse array in C#. Original idea was to use a normal `Dictionary<uint, TValue>` and wrap it in my own class to only expose the `TValue` type parameter. Turns out this is pretty slow.

So my next idea was to map each integer in the needed range (`UInt32.MinValue` to `UInt32.MaxValue`) to a bucket, of some size and use that. So I'm looking for a good way to map an unsigned integer X to a bucket Y, for example:

Mapping the numbers 0-1023 to 8 different buckets holding 128 numbers each, 0-127, 128-255.

But if someone has a better way of implementing a fast sparse array in C#, that would be most appreciated also.

Answer (score 6):

I, too, noticed that `Dictionary<K,V>` is slow when the key is an integer. I don’t know exactly why this is the case, but I wrote a faster hash-table implementation for `uint` and `ulong` keys:

- **[Efficient32bitHashTable and Efficient64bitHashTable](http://pastebin.com/Aq2L7NxQ)**

Caveats/downsides:

- The 64-bit one (key is `ulong`) is generic, but the other one (key is `uint`) assumes `int` values because that’s all I needed at the time; I’m sure you can make this generic easily.
- Currently the *capacity* determines the size of the hashtable forever (i.e. it doesn’t grow).

Comment: Is it really more efficient to have `element` be a class instead of a struct?

Comment: @Gabe: I don’t know, I didn’t test it. I suspect it makes little or no difference though. If you want to run some benchmarks, please feel free!

Comment: Are we talking about a lot slower than an array? Ie. So for relatively small, dense arrays, I would be better off with a boolean array to indicate set/not set?

Comment: As of 20110524 I have benchmarked Dictionary<K,V> and Efficient64bitHashtable<T> against each other using ulong keys (100 random values between 0 and 10_000) and Action(()=>{}) values with Jon Skeet's BenchmarkHelper framework for 10_000 iterations each and found that Dictionary<K,V> is about 223% faster. (Both structures were 3000%+ faster than a for/for loop structure.)  Increasing to 1_000 keys and 100_000 iterations resulted in Dictionary<K,V> being about 228% faster.  I am replacing production code that uses the iterative approach for ~7MM nightly trans. so this isn't merely an exercise.

Comment: @cfeduke: Did you take note of the 2nd caveat in my post here? What capacity did you specify? — Also, I wrote these in the times of .NET 2.0, so it may well be the case that `Dictionary<K,V>` is much faster in .NET 4.0, I didn’t test it.

Comment: I left the capacity at the default of 214373, and in my iteration test (using List) and Dictionary<K,V> I specified their capacity parameters as 214373 as well.  I am theorizing that the internals of Dictionary<K,V> have changed which is why I took the time to comment.  I am going to re-benchmark with the Efficient32bitHashTable just to be sure.

Comment: The link is dead, could you please repost it on something more stable like Github?

Comment: the link doesn't work -

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I fixed the link.

Answer (score 2):

There are a 101 different ways to implement sparse arrays depending on factors like:

- How many items will be in the array
- How are the items clustered together
- Space / speed trade of
- etc

Most textbooks have a section on sparse array, just doing a Google comes up with lots of hits.  You will then have to translate the code into C#, or just use the code someone else has written, I have found two without much effort (I don't know how good these are)

- [Use Specialty Arrays to Accelerate Your Code](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/37133/0/page/1)
- [SparseArray for C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/sparsearray.aspx)

Comment: To newcomers, note that in reality 101 is actually probably understating it.

Comment: -1 because "Learn how to design a spare array" is not helpful advise to someone trying to learn how to design a sparse array.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is an old question. Yet I have faced it in 2023. Still .Net does not have a sparse array.

Quick and dirty testing of available inrtinsic types on ~27 millions of records yielded these results:

**Load time (less is better):**

```
Dictionary<long, string> net7                100%
SortedList<long, string> net7                 90%
SortedList<long, string> net8                 62%
SortedDictionary<long, string> net7          120%
ImmutableSortedDictionary<long, string> net7 146%
FrozenDictionary<long, string> net8           74%
```

**Memory footprint (less is better):**

```
Dictionary<long, string> net7                100%
SortedList<long, string> net7                 78%
SortedList<long, string> net8                 78%
SortedDictionary<long, string> net7          105%
ImmutableSortedDictionary<long, string> net7 105%
FrozenDictionary<long, string> net8          100%
```

Access time was roughly the same.

`SortedList<long, string> net8` seems to be the winner.