# Does the .Net framework have constant indexed list

Tags: c#, .net

Many times when I do something in code I find the need for a `list with constant indexing`. What I mean by that is a list like the `List / List<T>` we all know and love that does not move items around (changes their index) on delete operations. Instead it leaves behind an empty slot that can be then filled with the next add operation.

My question is, specifically, does the .Net framework have such thing?

Comment: Yes I can just set items to null instead of removing them but it's by no way a good solution, When accessing an item I'll have to check if it's not null, I will not be able to use `Add` anymore, instead I'll have to try and find an empty (`null`) and then set it.

Comment: `Dictionary<int, T>` doesn't have any `Add` method that automatically determines the next available index. So, if using `Dictionary<int, T>` is an option for you, it seems like you don't really need an `Add(T)` method. Could you clarify what, specifically, you need and don't need?

Comment: @hvd Yes the `Dictionary` type does not support what I specified in my comment, when I used dictionaries I used them as a cheap hack when I was to lazy to write my own. I'll edit my question to clarify that.

Comment: Why don't you write your own?

Comment: Could you, probably, be more specific about what do you want achieve?

Comment: @DanielA.White I have written my own many times already, that is not my question. My question is "does the .Net framework have such thing?"

Comment: Then the answer is "no".

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798178/implementing-a-sparse-array-in-c-sharp-fastest-way-to-map-integer-to-a-specifi